# If the main function is called inside the reset handler, how other interrupts are handled?

Tags: c, arm, embedded

This is a sample code from a start up code for Tiva C, as you can see the main function is called inside the reset handler, and as i understand it's is the highest priority, so my question is how any other interrupt can be handled if we are still inside the reset handler?

````
```
; Reset Handler

Reset_Handler   PROC
            EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
            IMPORT  SystemInit
            IMPORT  __main
            LDR     R0, =SystemInit
            BLX     R0
            LDR     R0, =__main
            BX      R0
            ENDP
```
````

Comment: you are always within the reset handler if you wish to think of it that way.

Comment: the reset event handler simply gets you started/booted, it is not expected to return.  the other event and interrupt handlers can return if so desired.

Comment: and/or I am misunderstanding the question.  making assumptions about your code since you didnt provide enough detail.  address 0x00000000 is the reset exception entry point, other entry points are at 0x00000004, 0x00000008 and so on.  so the instruction at 0x00000000 needs to branch away in one instruction either b reset_handler or ldr pc,=reset handler. (or ldr pc,reset_handler_address, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reset is "special".  When the reset handler is invoked by a processor reset, instructions are executed in *thread mode*.  Necessarily so, since the reset vector is invoked on a power-on-reset (POR) - if the handler had to "return" where would it return to?

Also on reset in any case registers are reset to their defined reset state, and the stack pointer set to the address at the start of the table (in the case of am ARM Cortex-M at least), so there would be nowhere from which to fetch a return address - in fact the reset signal does not cause a return address to be stacked in any case. 
The whole point of a reset is to restart the processor in a known state. 
 Returning to the point at which the reset occurred makes little sense, and would not be likely to work given that the reset state of the processor is unlikely to be a suitable run-state for the "interrupted" code.

From the [ARM Cortex-M3 User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABBGBEC.html) (my ***emphasis***)  other ARM architectures may differ in the details, but not the general point.

> **2.3.2. Exception types** The exception types are:
>
> **Reset**
>
> Reset is invoked on power up or a warm reset. The exception model treats reset as a special form of exception. When reset is asserted,
>   the operation of the processor stops, potentially at any point in an
>   instruction. When reset is deasserted, execution restarts from the
>   address provided by the reset entry in the vector table. ***Execution
>   restarts as privileged execution in Thread mode.***
>   [...]

Answer (score 2):

I've found the pseudocode in the ARM architecture reference manuals to be quite helpful for answering this type of question. By "tiva c", I assume you are talking about the TM4C line of microcontrollers which are Cortex-M4 based MCUs. This means we will want to look at the [ARMv7-M architecture reference manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf).

Section "B1.5.5 Reset Behavior" has the pseudocode we are interested in. Here's a snippet (with the parts not relevant to the question elided out):

```
Asserting reset causes the processor to abandon the current execution 
state without saving it. On the deassertion of reset, all registers 
that have a defined reset value contain that value, and the processor
performs the actions described by the TakeReset() pseudocode.

// TakeReset()
// ============
TakeReset()    
    CurrentMode = Mode_Thread;
    PRIMASK<0> = '0'; /* priority mask cleared at reset */
    FAULTMASK<0> = '0'; /* fault mask cleared at reset */
    BASEPRI<7:0> = Zeros(8); /* base priority disabled at reset */
    // [...]
```

From the description we can note:

1. If the system is running and a reset is issued, the processor will always "abandon the current execution". So it is the "highest priority" thing that can happen if the MCU is running.
2. However, after the MCU restarts and the "TakeReset" logic starts to run, the "CurrentMode" the processor enters is actually **Thread mode**. ARMv7-M has two operation modes known as **Thread Mode** and **Handler Mode**. All interrupts/exceptions run in **Handler Mode** and normal code runs in **Thread Mode**. This tells us the reset path does **not** actually start like an interrupt/exception would. It's just running like normal code would.

Comment: long answer which does not answer the question

Comment: The confusion in the problem statement stemmed from: "and as i understand [the Reset_Handler] is the highest priority,". This answer explains why the code running after reset is not in fact at the highest priority and therefore can be interrupted.

Comment: all the thread, stack and another deliberations are not needed here